# Github Action CI/CD to EKS and ECR

Tags: docker, kubernetes, github-actions, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

i have an apps based on Node.js and i want to automation every step my deployment.
here my workflow.yml

```
name: marketplace-ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, staging ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, staging ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js 12
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12'
    - run:  npm ci
    - run:  npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
      
    - name: Cache npm
      uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1
    - run: npm t
    
    - name: copy env
      run: cp stag.dockerfile Dockerfile
      
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{AWS_SECRET_KEY}}
        aws-region: ap-southeast-1

    # login ECR
    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
      
    - name: Get short SHA
      id: slug
      run: echo "::set-output name=sha8::$(echo ${GITHUB_SHA} | cut -c1-8)"
      
    - name: Build and Push to ECR
    - uses: whoan/docker-build-with-cache-action@v5
      with:
        username: ${{AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}
        password: ${{AWS_SECRET_KEY}}
        registry: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        image_name: marketplace
        image_tag: "stag-${{ steps.slug.outputs.sha8 }},staging"
        
    - name: Get image name
      id: image
      run: echo "::set-output name=image::${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/<path url registry lo>:prod-${{ steps.slug.outputs.sha8 }}"

    - name: Build and push CONTAINER_NAME
      uses: ianbelcher/eks-kubectl-action@master
      with:
        aws_access_key_id: ${{AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}
        aws_secret_access_key: ${{AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}
        aws_region: ap-southeast-1
        cluster_name: stag-marketplace
        args: set image deployment/stag-marketplace stag-marketplace=${{ steps.image.outputs.image }}
```

and i have an error like this
`` every step must define a `uses` or `run` key ``

please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says

```
every step must define a `uses` or `run` key
```

Each step begins with a hyphen (`-`) and should contain `uses` or `run` keyword. Your workflow does not meet the requirements. For example, the fragment contains two steps

```
- name: Use Node.js 12
- uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '12'
```

The first one is invalid

```
- name: Use Node.js 12
```

It does not contain `uses` or `run` so you get the error.

It should be

```
- name: Use Node.js 12
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '12'
```

or you can omit the name and it still will be valid

```
- uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '12'
```

You have also the same erroneous case in

```
- name: Build and Push to ECR
- uses: whoan/docker-build-with-cache-action@v5
```

It should be

```
- name: Build and Push to ECR
  uses: whoan/docker-build-with-cache-action@v5
```

or simply

```
- uses: whoan/docker-build-with-cache-action@v5
```

As a rule, you cannot have a single `- name:` as the step definition. It should be followed either with `uses` or `run` without a hyphen as it's already added next to `name:`. A hyphen starts a new step and, as the error message says:

```
every step must define a `uses` or `run` key
```